# Can you estimate when a shrimp is going to give birth

Tags: health, aquarium

[image: my pregnant shrimp]

Now my shrimp is pregnant. I know I have been asking a lot of questions about my shrimp pregnancy but yes. Either ways, this is my sunkist shrimp. One of them. I want to see if it’s possible to tell when a shrimp will roughly give birth. I think that if I know when my shrimp babies will be born, I can prepare for time for an investigation of how the babies look like and stuff.

Please tell me from this photo when the babies will be born or even if it’s possible to guess! The main question is that about how to guess around when a shrimp will give birth if possible and your estimate when my will give birth.

Comment: It’s not really possible to guess. You can estimate based on when you first saw the shrimp pregnant. How much have you read up on Shrimp breeding? I recommend starting with the Wiki. It’s honestly super useful to understand your shrimp behaviors and breeding.

Comment: For instance- the eggs your shrimp are carrying may not even be fertilized by a male yet. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neocaridina_davidi